# What is the maximum templates limit in BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I wonder how many templates I can create for product and category pages? I did not find it on [Planform limits page](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Platform-Limits).

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit of 2500 total files in the theme bundle, but aside from that, there isn't a limit specific to custom product and category templates. A few other boundaries that might be helpful:

- Max bundle size of 50MB
- 5MB max for any single file within the bundle
- 1MB max for either the /templates or the parsed/templates directories within the bundle
- Max unzipped file size is 100MB

Comment: Does it relates to both blueprint and cornerstone engine?

Comment: This is only for Stencil.

Comment: So what are limits for Blueprint?

Comment: Blueprint has been deprecated for a few years now, but it doesn't go through a bundle process, so the restrictions above don't apply. Blueprint custom templates are stored in object storage (WebDAV) rather than within a theme bundle, so I don't believe there's a hard limit.